# Including JS in head or immediately after opening body tag

Tags: javascript

What is the difference between including Javascript in the `<head>` as opposed to immediately after the OPENING `<body>` tag?

Facebook Like widget is one example where they suggest placing the code immediately after the opening `<body>` tag.  SiteCatalyst also suggests this for their analytics code.

While there is an obvious difference between including the code in the `<head>` element as opposed to right before the closing `</body>` tag, I'm not sure what the difference is between the `<head>` and immediately after the opening `<body>` tag.

Comment: That's a good question, I'm not sure there is a difference either, but perhaps head and body are not handle the same way...

Comment: Personally can't think of any difference.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the JavaScript is outputting something into the DOM without a helper function (directly writing HTML), it would be important to have that JavaScript inside the `<body>`, however there should be no difference in this case wither it is right after `<body>` or right before `</body>`.

Typically, anything that is dependent on the DOM being loaded goes right before `</body>` because until the page renders to that point, it would be impossible for the full DOM to be loaded. My guess would be that these scripts don't depend on the DOM being loaded, but they do output HTML directly to the DOM (like a hidden `<input>` tag or something).

Comment: Did you mean, "in this case whether it is right after <body> or right before </head>"?

Comment: No, I meant after `<body>` or right before `</body>`. They are asking you to put the element inside of the `<body` tag, I am just saying that the functionality should work regardless of where you put it.

Comment: Gotcha.  I don't believe the FB widget example I used is outputting anything into the DOM (just asynchronously calling an external script), so in that example there may be no actual difference.  But what you said does make sense in other cases.

Answer (score 0):

When a browser encounters a script directive it loads a script before processing the rest of the page. So the lower a script is, the better. It can go immediately after closing the body tag or just before it. The best way is to load them asynchronously like this (Google Analytics example):

```
(function() {
        var ga = document.createElement('script');
        ga.type = 'text/javascript';
        ga.async = true;
        ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol 
          ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
        var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
        s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
    })();
```

Comment: Google say that you should put this script just before the closing head tag.

Comment: And I said "It can go immediately after closing the body tag or just before it.". From my experience it doesn't matter where.